# How to call appdelegate.swift after logout in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I have have been working on the FCM token. Initially, I can able to register FCM token and receive the token from FCM. 
My issue is while doing log out, I have been calling delete FCM token API call from the backend and it removes token from the device. After removing the FCM token, it moves to the login page controller but I could not able register FCM token again. While login I need to pass FCM token along with login API call.

here is the code I used to get FCM token in login viewController:

```
       var fcmval :String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.fcmTokenUpdated(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil)


}

deinit {
    //Don't forget to removeObserver
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil)
}

@objc func fcmTokenUpdated(notification:Notification){


    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: String]{

        if let c = userInfo["token"] {

            print(c)

            fcmval = c

            print("fcm token from app view controller:::", fcmval)

             let baseURL = "https://url"
             A8FlowBuilder(self).showLoginView(url: baseURL, fcm: fcmval ?? "")
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.fcmTokenUpdated(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil)
}
```

How to register FCM token after log out?

Comment: can you post the code of what you do in logout?

Answer (score 0):

Save it in defaults / global vaiable

```
@objc func fcmTokenUpdated(notification:Notification){  
  if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: String] , let c = userInfo["token"] {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(c,"Token")
   }
}
```

then access it anywhere

Comment: whether it will register in FCM

Comment: its supposed that you do this only in login action

Comment: it does not work. because, My logout function in SDK in app side. I am logout from sdk side.